# Increase upload_max_filesize via Forge

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, forge

Error: *413 Request Entity Too Large*

I have attempted to increase `upload_max_filesize` to `20M` using the `Edit PHP FPM Configuration` and `Edit PHP CLI Configuration` tools in Laravel Forge. It successfully saves my settings, but the changes don't seem to take affect. I have tried restarting nginx and the server.

Environment:

- AWS EC2
- nginx

Comment: It doesn't seem to have helped. I still get "413 Request Entity Too Large".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was missing. It's working now. 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was missing a piece. Here's the whole answer.

**Nginx Configuration**

Add the following line to **http** or **server** or **location context** to increase the size limit in nginx.conf:

```
# set client body size to 20M #
client_max_body_size 20M;
```

**PHP Configuration**

Edit php.ini and set the following directives:

```
;This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate
memory_limit = 256M

;The maximum size of an uploaded file.
upload_max_filesize = 20M

;Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 30M
```

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/

Comment: This would be great to do as a Laravel Recipe! Anyone have any experience with recipes?

Answer (score 18):

As @dave-alvarez mentioned, there is a setting in Laravel Forge to do this.

- Select your server & choose PHP from the left menu.
- Set *Max File Upload Size* as a megabyte integer (with no trailing unit).
- Confirm your change by going to the bottom of the page & clicking the *Files* pull-up, *Edit PHP FPM Configuration* option. You can search the `php.ini` for `upload_max_filesize`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 17):

*Updating since this is the first search engine result for a search on this topic:*

Forge now has a built-in setting you can update by going to the server details page and then clicking on PHP from the menu on the left. You'll see a form to change the max file size.

Comment: Thanks for that i was trying to work out why all my changes were not working , easy to just do it via the interface.